# Xamarin Saving List To Shared Preferences

Tags: database, listview, xamarin

Im working on a restaurant application.  Would it be a good idea to hold the menu items in sharedPreference? That sounds more simple to me but im afraid of losing the data. It happened me few times when the app crashed data was lost.

Note: Im not using xamarin forms.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xamarin ListView display item from SQLite Database C# Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34100382/xamarin-listview-display-item-from-sqlite-database-c-sharp-android)

Comment: ListViews and Adapters : https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/working_with_listviews_and_adapters/

Comment: if your db is running on another machine that is, by definition, not "local".  The machine with the db either needs to act as a server for webservices, or you need to have a local copy of the db on your device.

Comment: Okay my first question is answered. Thanks.

Comment: SharedPreferences is not really meant to be a primary datastore for your app.  Using SQLite is typically the recommended approach for local datastores on the device.

Comment: So you recommend creating a database on android and using it.